# XML file as JSP script

Tags: xml, jsp, spring-mvc

I'd like to generate an XML file with a JSP script. The catch is that I want my JSP script to be a Spring-MVC view, and thereby inherit the view's objects. When I write

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

in a JSP file in Eclipse, I get an error saying "Processing instruction not closed". Why is this? Is it possible to do what I want to do, and is this the way to go about it?

Comment: Also, if I made a scriptlet in <% %> tags, would I be able to access the objects I inherit from my view in this scriptlet?

Comment: ignore the eclipse error and try to run it.

Answer (score 0):

In case you haven't already figured this one out, here's my ugly fix for this problem:

```
<%="<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" %>
```

It avoids the "Processing instruction not closed" error and the red squigglies covering the entire document. There's also supposedly a way to turn off the validation for this in Eclipse entirely, but said validation comes in handy more often than not IMHO.